# How to make sure that a table follows a specific float?

Tags: floats

I have a graphic that shows an object with numbers for explanation, and a tabular that lists and explains these numbers.
For the graphic I use a `figure` environment, for the tabular a `table` environment.

Since these two types of floats are handled separately by LaTeX, the tabular could be placed before the graphic, which isn’t intended.
I could use the `float` package and [H] option, but I’d prefer to keep the two floats floating (because LaTeX know best)!

Another option would be to use `figure` environments for both floats, but then the table ends up in the list of figures instead of in the list of tables.

How can I get the two different floats to appear in the correct order?

Comment: put _both_ in a `figure` environment and use for the tabular `\captionof{table}{blah blah}` from the package `capt-of`. The KOMA classes have the command already defined.

Comment: Thanks, I use the scrreprt class and regularly look up stuff in scrguide.pdf, but this time, I didn’t think it would have this info! Would you make this into an answer?

Comment: Do you need to have distinct captions for the two objects?

Comment: @Philipp: done ...

Comment: @egreg Not necessarily. With two floats, it would have been necessary. The solution mentioned in scrguide (putting two minipages inside one figure environment) supersedes that necessity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put both in a `figure` environment and use for the `tabular` the command `\captionof{table}{blah blah}` from the package `capt-of`. The KOMA classes have the command already defined.

The same is possible with `table` environment and for the image `\captionof{figure}{blah blah}`